# Page, row compression to check on Database level - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Need a SQL Script to check the object level page and row compression on each table for the database.

I tried using the ms_foreachdb script to loop each table to check the page compression, which is not working.

Comment: You need to show us your query so that we can help you

Comment: EXEC Sp_estimate_data_Compression_Savings
@schema_name='dbo'
@object_name='adcd'
@indexid=NULL
@partition_number=NULL
@data_compression='PAGE'

Comment: This query runs on a particular table, but I need to run each object in a specific database once.

Comment: What is your script that includes using ms_foreachdb?

Comment: ms_foreachdb is not working. I cancelled the query. do you have any script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine msforeachdb with msforeachtable.

This is a very raw sample to get you started:

```sql
exec sp_MSforeachdb N'

if db_id(''¤'') > 4 -- Skip system dbs
BEGIN
    use [¤]
    exec sp_msforeachtable ''
    print ''''¤ ?''''
    declare @tb sysname = PARSENAME(''''?'''',1)
    
    exec Sp_estimate_data_Compression_Savings @object_name = @tb, @schema_name = ''''dbo'''', @index_id = null, @partition_number = null, @data_compression=row
    
    '',@replacechar = N''?''
END
', @replacechar = N'¤'
```

The biggest pain with these two procs is that amount of quotes one have to make. I think you might be better off with two nested cursors looping stuff from databases etc

EDIT: Improved script a bit. But like i said, you better be off creating a cursor script yourself

Comment: the above script is throwing the error - Msg 1088, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_estimate_data_compression_savings, Line 60 [Batch Start Line 9]
Cannot find the object "XXXXXXXXXXXX" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

I have a permissions but it showing the same error for all of the tables.

Comment: yeah, i forgot to actually change the database context:/ fixed now me thinks

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, and suggestions.
Is there any script to release the page and row compression in database level, not the object level.